# Add Script in aggregation - Elastic Search

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation

I want to add a script to all the hits that i get in bucket. here is the query

```
{
"aggregations": {

"groupByChains": {
  "terms": {
    "field": "chain.id",
    "size": 100,
    "min_doc_count": 1,
    "shard_min_doc_count": 0,
    "show_term_doc_count_error": false,
    "order": [
      {
        "_count": "desc"
      },
      {
        "_key": "asc"
      }
    ]
  },
  "aggregations": {
    "topHits": {
      "top_hits": {
        "from": 0,
        "size": 100,
        "version": false,
        "seq_no_primary_term": false,
        "explain": false
      }
    }
  }
}
```

}
}

when i get hits inside the bucket, i want add a field with distance and i have script for that. so can anyone help me in guyiding where to add the script

Answer (score 0):

You can add script field in top_hits

Example

```
{
  "aggs": {
    "NAME": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "quantity",
        "size": 10
      },
      "aggs": {
        "NAME": {
          "top_hits": {
            "size": 10,
            "_source": "*", 
            "script_fields": {
              "distance": {
                "script": "1 + 1"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```